What are some things I should keep in mind as I enters Masters?
So I recently received an offer from a fairly prestigious university for an MSCS degree. I want to continue to a PhD, and I wanted to know if there were any words of wisdom from people who have gone through that route, and their do's and don'ts. I feel like I didn't take advantage of my university resources in undergrad (mainly because of covid, but also because I didn't know stuff like research under professors existed until second sem of second year) and I wanted to avoid that.
I'll be a 100% honest, I'm not completely sure about the exact topic that I want to research about, but I do have an idea of what field I am interested in. I'm a bit lost about how to start performing research as well. Would I be expected to email professors and ask for RAship straight up, or would I be expected to work with them first and then be granted an RAship?
Tldr: Give me words of wisdom for a masters student who wants to do a phd

and welcome to academia.SE! Your question might be considered too broad, and might even have been asked before. I'm relatively new here myself, so I'm not sure.
During your master's, you should focus on three things:

Learning as much as possible.

Discovering what area you might want to research for your PhD, and starting the research process (even better if you can get some publication(s)).

Developing strong relationships with professors, both because it helps (1) and (2), and because these professors will write you letters of recommendation to get into PhD programs.


Your question about whether or not to start a "research assistantship" right away is going to depend on the field of study, the country, and the specific university. I recommend you ask that question to the person who accepted you. That person is likely the chair of the graduate admissions committee and perhaps is the graduate chair of the department.
I have a PhD in math and a master's in computer science. In those fields, in the USA, it's normal for students to start with coursework, then transition into independent study courses with faculty members whose research they are interested in. Those latter courses cover specialized knowledge that is required to get started in the specific research of the faculty member. However, it's also normal to have a master's advisor and to do research in their lab. Where I got my degree, students chose their master's advisor during the first year, but not before they started. But, again, different places might do it differently.
Because the one-on-one relationship with your master's advisor is so imporant, I recommend you take the time to get to know them and their work (and, to hear from other grad students who work with them) before you decide who will be your advisor. In your first semester you can shop around with different potential advisors and labs, while taking courses. I don't think that would set you back relative to deciding now which lab to be in and then already being in that lab on day 1.
Once you pick a master's advisor, do try to meet with them as much as possible. Where I did my degree, one hour per week was the standard. Also, try to get into good time management habits so that you do your work uniformly throughout the week, instead of in a giant rush right before that weekly meeting. Do go to seminars (especially graduate student seminars) and ask lots of questions. Focus on learning and recognize that you have a very limited amount of time there, so it's important to make the most of it!
Congrats on starting this exciting next chapter of your life!
